# Does navagraha tarpana in sandhyavandan reduce the astrological effects?

Tags: vedas, navagraha, sandhyavandanam

In sandhyavandan, subsequent to Argya to Sun, we have navagraha tarpana to be offered to nine grahas - aditya, somam, agarakam, budham, brhaspatim, sukram, sanaiscaram, rahum and ketum.

When we offer tarpana to grahas - does any scripture say that these tarpanas to grahas reduce astrological effects on a individual?

Comment: AFAIK, we dont offer tarpanas to Navagrahas anywhere in Sandhyanandana

Comment: Well in yajur veda sandhya we follow we have navaragaha tarpana. Vaishnavism doesnt have navagraha tarpana. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/sandhya.pdf Please tell me where Navagraha Tarpana is there. I follow Smarta

Comment: See the below answer @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru There are various ways of doing the same thing in Hinduism. Some do it in one way others in some other way. The website you linked is related to Sri Vaishnavas, They might not do it but others might. There are Rig Vedi Sandhya, Yajurvedi Sandhya etc. We need to check their manuals.

Comment: Have checked many couldn't find Navagraha Tarpana anywhere Rickross Ji @Rickross may be its there in other works..

Comment: Great find. I checked my book and it shows 3 Tarpanas for 3 times of day and never includes Navagraha. You are right this might be optional or subsidary. @Archit

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru see the Pauranika one. The Shukla Yajurveda doesn’t have Navagaha tarpana. Only Krishna has and Pauranika (as mentioned by Rickross) have. In Krishna Yajurveda Idk why some Vaishnavas omit the tarpana.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Sandhyanga Tarpana by certain Sampradayas, Deva Tarpana is done. And Navagraha Tarpana comes under Deva Tarpana.

The book  ["STOTRA KAVACHA ( SHIELD OF PRAYERS)](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/STOTRA_KAVACHA.pdf), hosted at Kamakoti.org, is comprised of various Stotras and Kavcahas dedicated to various deities, which are found in Puranas.

The book also have two Puranic methods of performing Sandhya. One from the Devi Bhagavatam and another one from the Narada Purana. The Narada Purana method have Navagraha Tarpana as a limb of the whole ritual (check on p.128 of the PDF).

> Sayamkala Sandhya (Evening) Mantra states:
>
> Agnischa ma manyuscha manyupatayascha manyu kritebhyah Paapebhyo
> rakshantaam yadanha paapamakaarsham, Manasa vaachaa hastaabhyam
> Padbyaam udarena sishnaa Ahastadalumpatu, yat kincha duritam mayi
> idamaham maamamritayonau satye jyothishi juhomi swaha/
>
> ( Let all the Deities of Fire, fury and ferocity safeguard me from
> their attack on me due to the unpardonable sins perpetrated by me by
> the day by my mind, stomach, sex organ; may I be purified me of
> despicable deeds and qualify me to proceed on the path of Moksha.
> Achamana-Punarmarjana and Marjana be followed with the Mantra viz.
>
> Dadhikravinno akaarisham jishnorasvasya vajinah, surabhi no mukha
> karat prana Aagumshi tarishat/
>
> (May the Lord who is the Sustainer, Administrator and Evaluator in the
> form of Hayagriva the Victorious and the Seat of knowledge be
> worshipped to facilitate our Life without any obstacle). This Mantra
> may be followed by the afore-mentioned Mantra Aapo hi shtha while
> sprinkling water on the head of the devotee and touching the feet and
> thereafter recite Apo janayata cha nah while water is thrown round the
> head.
>
> Arghya pradaanam: Recite the Gayatri Mantra pour water thrice to the
> East in the morning, face north and pour water twice in standing
> position and face west in sitting posture as follows:
>
> Om Bhurbhuvassavah, Tat Saviturvarenyam bhargo devasya dhimahi, dhiyo
> yo nah prachodayaat/
>
> Praanaayama should be done there after.
>
> **Deva Tarpana:Adityam Tapayami, Somam Tarpayami, Angaarakam Tarpayami, Budham Tarpayami, Brihaspatim Tarpayami, Sukram
> Tarpayami,Shanaischaram Tarpayami, Rahum Tarpayami, Ketu Tarpayami//**
> Keshavam Tarpayami, Narayanam Tarpayami, Govindam Tarpayami, Vishnum
> Tarpayami, Madhusudanam Tarpayami, Trivikramam Tarpayami, Vaamanam
> Tarpayami, Shridharam Tarpayami, Hrishikesham Tarpayami, Damodaram
> Tarpayami.
>
> Gayatri Avahaana: Omityekaaksaram Brahma, Agnirdevata Bhrahma
> ityaarsham Gayatreem Chhandam Paramaatmam Swarupam, Sayujyam
> viniyogam/

Now, Tarpana, like Homa etc. is a way of worshipping the deities. And once worshipped these Navagrahas get appeased and they stop producing negative effects in the individual horoscopes.
 
This is mentioned in the Yajnvalkya Smriti:

> **CCCVII. —Whenever a planet has a bad aspect (in the horoscope of a person), that person should worship with great care specially that
> particular good planet. For Brahma has given this boon to them *"Being
> honoured you will honour him"*—307.**
>
> CCCVIII. —By lords of men should be worshipped with greatest care the
> planets because the rise and fall of monarchs is dependent upon the
> planets, so also the origin and destruction of the worlds.—308.

So, once these Grahas are duly appeased by Tarpanam, their negative astrological aspects are bound to get reduced.

Comment: Perfectly  answered with proper scriptural references.

Comment: Tarpana is 'one of the many ways' to appease the planets right? So the quote from Yajnavalkya smriti is explicitly refering to 'Tarpana' or any kind of remedy?

Comment: Not necessarily tarpana only .. Homa, Puja, mantra japa of the Grahas also will have similar outcomes @LSSJBroly

Comment: Thank you......