# Is Tarpanam a part of Sandhyavandanam?

Tags: sandhyavandanam

Is Tarpanam a part of Sandhyavandanam?. I have seen many books, each showing a different. In some books, there is no tarpanam. Does Tarpanam appear in the Rigveda, Yarjurveda, and Samaveda Sandhyavandanam? Or does it added later?

Comment: See this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/48082

Comment: keshavadi tarpanam with only water is part of sandhya. pitru tarpan with water and sesame is not